# What is the grammatical name and function

Tags: terminology, syntactic-analysis

> But few realize **that we are all adversely affected by a pollutant so common that it tends to be overlooked**.

What is the grammatical name and function of the bolded part?

Answer (score 2):

It's a [subordinate clause](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependent_clause).

> In linguistics, a dependent clause (or a subordinate clause) is a clause that augments an independent clause with additional information, but which cannot stand alone as a sentence. Dependent clauses either modify the independent clause of a sentence or serve as a component of it.

That *that* after *realize* is a dead giveaway. In fact it's called a "subordinating *that*". The Wikipedia article mentions a couple more of such "dependent words".

Comment: +1 Also, it's a *noun clause*, a dependent clause serving as a noun, the direct object of the verb *realize*.